# How to pass variable for columnlist ( to_json ) function in Spark-sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a jsonType output column in my spark-application - where I need to pass the dynamic column list to to_json function as an argument - I an able to achieve this using static list of function, but not as a argument/or parameter to application. please refer to working code

*****working code*****

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("newcol",lit(to_json(struct("c1","c2","c3"))))
```

***non-working code***

```
val columnList = "c1,c2,c3"
val df2 = df.withColumn("newcol",lit(to_json(struct(columnList))))  // using variable to pass the columns
```

Can you please help to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
val columnList = Seq("c1", "c2", "c3")
val df2 = df.withColumn("newcol", to_json(struct(columnList.map(col): _*)))
```

`lit` is not needed in your code because you're not constructing any literal column.

Or you can do:

```
val columnList = "c1,c2,c3"
val df2 = df.withColumn("newcol", to_json(struct(columnList.split(",").map(col): _*)))
```